# VBA: if N matches a numbers in a pattern then do something

Tags: vba, design-patterns

Hi bit of a Monday morning puzzle:

I have a series of numbers that always starts at 1 but could be any length. whats the best method for matching numbers that fit my pattern?

The pattern in question is as below (I want to do something on the bold numbers)

**1**,2,3,**4,5**,6,7,**8,9**,10,11,**12,13**.....

I've got a few ideas but they're all messy/ugly. What I really want is the most elegant way to do solve the problem without manually creating a list of numbers!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it correctly

```
If (N Mod 4) = 0 Or (N Mod 4) = 1 Then
```

Comment: That'll do it! Thanks bud!

Comment: You could even shorten it by writing: `if (N mod 4)<=1 then`

Answer (score -1):

this macro gets the required patter. If starts from row 2 till the last row and works on every 4th & 5th entry.

```
Sub Pattern()
Dim i, temp As Integer

l = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(1, 1).Value = "*"
For k = 2 To l
 temp = temp + 1

    If temp = 3 Then
    Cells(k, 3).Value = "*" 'do something here
    End If
    If temp = 4 Then
    Cells(k, 3).Value = "*" 'do something here
    temp = "0"
    End If

Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend reading [VBA Best Practices](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5410/use-descriptive-variable-naming). (1) Always use `Option Explicit` and declare all your variables. (2) You **must** specify a type for **every** variable `Dim i, temp As Integer` leaves `i` as `Variant`, also don't ever use Integer if not using an old 16 bit API, use Long: `Dim i As Long, temp As Long`. (3) fully qualify your cells/ranges etc, [never assume the worksheet](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet).

Comment: (4) Also never use fixed row counts like `Range("a65536")` because different Excel versions have different max. row counts. Always use `.Range("A" & .Rows.Count)`